# Apple Subscription Offer Codes do not work when crossgrading

Tags: ios, swift, subscription, ios14

I'm trying to use the Offer Codes feature Apple introduced in iOS 14. While it mostly works we are receiving reports of issues from our users that they can't actually redeem the offer.

From the documentation:

> Select the customer eligibility for your offer. You can choose any combination of new, active, or expired users.
>
> - New: Users who have never subscribed to any subscription product within the group.
> - **Active: Users who are currently subscribed to a product within the group.**
> - Expired: Users who were previously subscribed to a product within the group, but whose subscription has expired.

Our subscription group has following plans (only 1 level):

- 1 Month
- 3 Months
- 6 Months
- 12 Months

We have created an Offer Code for the 12 Months plan.

[image: Offer Code Setup]

Based on the documentation users who are currently subscribers on the 1m, 3m, 6m plans should therefore be able to crossgrade using this offer.

[image: Apple Docs]

But users that actually try to do this receive an error:

> This offer cannot be redeemed with your current subscription.

[image: Error Screenshot]

I checked and there are in the same subscription group and users can crossgrade without a problem if not using the offer. Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a question concerning a service that Apple, Inc offers is not really a programming issue.  Besides, nobody here represents the big company.